# Join two queries into two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I am new to PostgreSQL and I'm learning a lot in a short time but haven't learnt everything yet so forgive me if this is a simple question.
I have searched for this and a JOIN should bring them together but with my setup I can't get it to work.

**PROBLEM**
I have a WITH statement that has all the criteria for what I want to search for
Then I wish you perform two SELECT queries, one for each user (only 2 users will be searched for at one time)

**DATA**
The Data consists of time and an the count of the amount, there will be criteria in the with clause where only the username is used further in the queries.

**EXAMPLE**

```
HOUR AMOUNT
01 200
02 300
03 500
04 800
```

Using a UNION I get both queries in the same column

```
HOUR AMOUNT
01 200
01 75
02 300
02 50
03 500
03 21
04 800
04 300
```

But I simply want the second query to appear in a new column

```
HOUR AMOUNT AMOUNT2
01 200     75   
02 300     50
03 500     21
04 800     300
```

I've simplified the SQL so it's not too long:

```
WITH My_With AS (
...
)


SELECT time, count(time) AS Column_1
FROM My_With
WHERE
    username= 'jon' 
GROUP BY time

UNION

SELECT time, count(time) AS Column_2
FROM My_With
WHERE
    username= 'bob' 
GROUP BY time
ORDER BY time   
;
```

I know this is probably really simple but I just can't figure it out, I've managed to put the second set of amounts into a second column but it still generates 2 tows for the time.

Comment: The sample data has an hour column, but the queries have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT time, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE username = 'jon') as cnt_jon,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE username = 'bob') as cnt_bob
FROM My_With
GROUP BY time;
```

Or, with less typing:

```
SELECT time, 
       SUM( (username = 'jon')::int ) as cnt_jon,
       SUM( (username = 'bob')::int ) as cnt_bob
FROM My_With
GROUP BY time;
```

Comment: You're a legend